# Can I control the way the CountVectorizer vectorizes the corpus in scikit learn?

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn, text-parsing, corpus

I am working with a CountVectorizer from scikit learn, and I'm possibly attempting to do some things that the object was not made for...but I'm not sure.

In terms of getting counts for occurrence:

```
vocabulary = ['hi', 'bye', 'run away!']
corpus = ['run away!']
cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
print X.toarray()
```

gives:

```
[[0 0 0 0]]
```

What I'm realizing is that the CountVectorizer will break the corpus into what I believe is unigrams:

```
vocabulary = ['hi', 'bye', 'run']
corpus = ['run away!']
cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
print X.toarray()
```

which gives:

```
[[0 0 1]]
```

Is there any way to tell the CountVectorizer exactly how you'd like to vectorize the corpus? Ideally I would like an outcome along the lines of the first example.

In all honestly, however, I'm wondering if it is at all possible to get an outcome along these lines:

```
vocabulary = ['hi', 'bye', 'run away!']
corpus = ['I want to run away!']
cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocabulary)
X = cv.fit_transform(corpus)
print X.toarray()

[[0 0 1]]
```

I don't see much information in the documentation for the fit_transform method, which only takes one argument as it is.  If anyone has any ideas I would be grateful.  Thanks!

Comment: What you want is the `tokenizer` argument to `CountVectorizer`, which should be a callable that takes in a string and returns a list of tokens.  However, it's not clear from your post exactly what rules you want to use to tokenize the input.

Answer (score 7):

The parameter you want is called `ngram_range`. You pass in a tuple `(1,2)` to the constructor to get unigrams and bigrams. However, the vocabulary you pass in needs to be a `dict` with ngrams as keys and integers as values.

```
In [20]: print CountVectorizer(vocabulary={'hi': 0, u'bye': 1, u'run away': 2}, ngram_range=(1,2)).fit_transform(['I want to run away!']).A
[[0 0 1]]
```

Note the default tokeniser removes the exclamation mark at the end, so the last token is `away`. If you want more control over how the string is broken up into tokens, follow @BrenBarn's comment.

Comment: The vocabulart is "Either a Mapping (e.g., a dict) where keys are terms and values are indices in the feature matrix, **or an iterable over terms.**" (from the docs)