# Sklearn Countvectorizer on custom vocabulary

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I have a set of webpages and i was in the process of getting the webpage count matrix. I tried to use the standard [Countvectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) from sklearn but not getting the required results. The sample code is as below:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['www.google.com www.google.com', 'www.google.com www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']
vocab = {'www.google.com':0, 'www.facebook.com':1}
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(X.toarray())
```

It gives

```
['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']
[[0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]
 [0 0]]
```

But the required result is

```
['www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']
[[2 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 0]
 [0 1]]
```

How do we apply countvectorizer on such a custom vocabulary?

Answer (score 2):

As per the input from a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24007812/can-i-control-the-way-the-countvectorizer-vectorizes-the-corpus-in-scikit-learn?rq=1), the issue occured because of the tokenizer. 
A customer tokenizer was written and now it works.

```
def mytokenizer(text):
    return text.split()

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ['www.google.com www.google.com', 'www.google.com www.facebook.com', 'www.google.com', 'www.facebook.com']
vocab = {'www.google.com':0, 'www.facebook.com':1}
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab, tokenizer = mytokenizer)
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(X.toarray())
```