# CountVectorizer() in Python is returning all zeros when I pass a custom vocabulary list

Tags: python, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

foo = ["the Cat is :", "is smart now"]
cv = CountVectorizer(vocabulary = foo)
new_list =["the Cat is : the most","is smart now"]
data = cv.fit_transform(new_list).toarray()
print(data)
```

The code is returning the following:

```
[[0 0]
[0 0]]
```

But I want it to return:

```
[[1 0]
[0 1]]
```

I tried to adjust the parameters being passed to `CountVectorizer()` but nothing seems to fix it. Any advice??

Comment: Does this help you out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55573279/sklearn-countvectorizer-on-custom-vocabulary - Take note of how they define their vocab, it needs to be a dictionary as per the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Comment: From my understanding of the documentation:
vocab = ["the"] or vocab = {'the':0} both work and I tested the code. But if I try adding space in the string to have:
vocab = ["the cat"] or vocab = {'the cat':0}
I get all zeros

Comment: You're right, I read callable not iterable, my apologies. As for the rest, this is because of the tokenisation as per the first link. Tokenising the string gives `[['The', 'cat', 'is', 'the', 'most'], ['is', 'smart' 'now']]`. Your tokeniser will have to return the desired tokens to match the vocab. From the link, you can see how to define your own tokeniser to do this. Otherwise, you may want to reconsider why you are trying to use `CountVectorizer` for the task and if it is the best or most desirable approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_preprocessor(text):
    return text

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = ["The cat is ! the most","is smart now"]
vocab = ['The cat is !', 'the most']
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=vocab,ngram_range=(1,4), preprocessor=my_preprocessor, token_pattern = '[a-zA-Z0-9$&+,:;=?@#|<>.^*()%!-]+')
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print(X.toarray())
```

I by bypassed the `preprocessor` and set the `token_pattern` to fix the issue.
Thank you [fam-woodpecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12023921/fam-woodpecker)

Comment: In my case I was using `CountVectorizer` after `TfidfVectorizer` to save the count matrix for future use (to be used with `TfidfTransformer`). So have same `ngram_range` in both `CountVectorizer` and `TfidfVectorizer`. I had different `ngram_range` hence `CountVectorizer` resulted in all zeros.